# Best way to removea space from this loop. (beginner)

Tags: loops

I have been working on this for a while and i cant seem to remove the white space from the end of the increment of printed numbers. (ex if input -15, 30 then output is -15 -5 5 15 25(with a unwanted whitespace here). I still want spacing between the rest of my values, just not at the end.

user_int1 = int(input())

user_int2 = int(input())

if user_int1 > user_int2:

```
print("Second integer can't be less than the first.")
```

else:

```
while user_int1 <= user_int2:

    print(user_int1, end=' ')

    user_int1 += 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd replace the loop with:

```
print(*range(user_int1, user_int2+1, 10), end='')
```

Of course, `user_int1` will be unchanged thereafter.